# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection while running puppeteer script

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise, puppeteer

I get a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection while doing simple web scraping with puppeteer, I have used the exact same code in another projects and it worked, I dont know why it aint working now. Full eror next line:

```
node .\scrapers.js
```

```
(node:9748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined
    at scrapeChannel (C:\Users\João Teixeira\OneDrive\code\learning\js\webscrapingapp\server\scrapers.js:10:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

`(node:9748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

```
(node:9748) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.
```

In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here's the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrapeChannel(url) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="text"]');
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const name = await text.jsonValue();

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="img"]');
    const src = await el2.getProperty('src');
    const avatarURL = await src.jsonValue();
    console.log({name, avatarURL})
    browser.close();

    return {name, avatarURL}
}
scrapeChannel('https://www.youtube.com/user/Microsoft');
```

Comment: use try/catch in async/await

Comment: I did as you said and now it just logs this:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined
    at scrapeChannel (C:\Users\João Teixeira\OneDrive\code\learning\js\webscrapingapp\server\scrapers.js:10:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

But in the puppeteer docs its like it exists

Comment: either el or el2 are undefined - so ...

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `page.$x` (after being `await`ed) is not returning one iterable with at least one element OR the first element of the returned iterable is `undefined`.
Thus, `el` or `el2` (depending on the line they are) is being assigned with `undefined`. Since `undefined` does not have a property `getProperty`, it throws. You are not catching that error, hence the notice.

As @Jaromanda X said, use `try`/`catch` inside the `async` function. Or, since `async` functions return a Promise, use `scrapeChannel('https://www.youtube.com/user/Microsoft').catch( /**/ );` to catch any error throw inside that function, avoiding the Node.js `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.